# validate height width of image in jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation plugin for form validation. But I have to validate image height width also. I searched on google. But I didn't get.

I want  height: 150px and width: 300px in logo to validate. If image height and width is equalto my given dimensions. Then form will be post.

My image form is:

```
 <div class="col-md-6 mb-50">
   <span class="input">
     <label class="" for="cf-website" style="font-weight: 500;">Upload Logo </label>
       <input class="input__field cf-validate check-image-size" type="file" id="logo" name="logo" accept="image/png,image/jpeg" />
 </div>
```

MY js is: I am validating complete form. Please ignore other fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('form[id="submit_form"]').validate({
  rules: {
    username: {
        maxlength: 40,
    },
    business_title: {
        maxlength: 40,
    },
    designation_qualification: {
        maxlength: 60,
    },
    business_speciality: {
        maxlength: 50,
    },
    contact: {
        maxlength: 16,
        number: true,
    },
    email: {
        email: true,
    },
    website: {
        maxlength: 100,
    },
    addres: {
         maxlength: 100,
    },
    description: {
         maxlength: 115,
    }
  },
  messages: {
    username: {
      maxlength: 'Maximum 40 characters allowed'
    },
    business_title: {
      maxlength: 'Maximum 40 characters allowed'
    },
    designation_qualification: {
      maxlength: 'Maximum 60 characters allowed'
    },
    business_speciality: {
      maxlength: 'Maximum 50 characters allowed'
    },
    contact: {
      maxlength: 'Maximum 16 characters allowed',
      number: 'Please enter number only'
    },
    email: {
      email: 'Enter a valid email'
    },
    website: {
      maxlength: 'Maximum 100 characters allowed'
    },
    addres: {
      maxlength: 'Maximum 100 characters allowed'
    },
    description: {
      maxlength: 'Maximum 115 characters allowed'
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank u for reply....But I how to validate with jquery validation plugin?

Comment: AFAIK the jquery validation plugin can't do that out of the box, you need to add some sort of a custom rule

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: The second answer in the marked duplicate is specifically for how to do this in jquery validator